# IPv6 SSH Tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, ipv6, tunnel

I'm setting up a tunnel with `ssh -w` and I would like to route IPv6 traffic through it. The remote machine is a server on the Internet with several IPv6 addresses assigned

What I am doing is:

```
local# ssh -w 0:0 remote.example.com
```

`remote.example.com` is an IPv4 address and the ssh connection goes over IPv4.

Then I assign `tun0` IPv6 addresses on both hosts

```
remote# ip a add fd00::ffff:1 dev tun0
local# ip a add fd00::ffff:2 dev tun0
```

At this point they can both ping eachother's fd00::/48 address.

I enable IPv6 forwarding on the remote server by setting:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Now I would like to be able to route `local`'s IPv6 traffic through tun0. `local` can connect to `remote` via IPv4 so the only IPv6 route it should need is default to `tun0`
Here's what I tried so far:

```
local# ip -6 r add default via fd00::ffff:1 dev tun0 
local# ip -6 r del default via gw dev wls0  # delete old default v6 route
```

However at this point I am not getting IPv6 connectivity on `local`, the packets are not routed by `remote`:

```
local# ping 2001:4860:4860::8888 
PING 2001:4860:4860::8888(2001:4860:4860::8888) 56 data bytes
From fd00::ffff:1 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

What do I need to set up on the `remote` server so that it passes the packets on?

Comment: Have you enabled SSH to listen on ipv6: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bsd-unix-configuring-ssh-listen-ipv6-addresses/ . And when pinging ipv6 adresses you need to use ping6.. Have you checked your SSH logs in /var/log? By the way for a VPN tunnel I would recommend OpenVPN or wireguard.

Comment: @Ace no, I would imagine that SSH would push IPv6 packets through the existing tunnel set up on IPv4. And that is what happens as the `Address unreachable` answer comes back from remote's tunnel end. Also for the sake of the excercise I would like to use SSH's tunneling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several reasons for that message:

- the `remote` host has route available to that destination (you said it has several IPv6 addresses, but you didn't say it has a default route);
- it has no route available to that destination *matching this source* (it may have only routes that match specific source prefixes, or it may have policy rules in `ip rule` selecting between different routing tables);
- its firewall "forward" chain rejects packets from this source.

Use `ip -6 route get 2001:4860:4860::8888 from fd00::ffff:2` to check what routing decision would be made.

However, in general, **you need to assign a global address to the `local` system.** For one, it can't really *receive* packets from the Internet without one, and very likely the gateway behind the `remote` system will refuse to let it *send* packets to the Internet from a "wrong" address (it might be doing BCP38 spoofed address filtering).

(If `remote` has a global IPv6 prefix routed to it, you can either use that prefix for the tunnel itself, or route it across the tunnel via fd00::ffff:2 so that `local` could decide what to do with it. If a routed prefix is unavailable, then typically *at least* some "on-link" addresses will be available, which you can still route further by enabling NDP proxying using the `ndpresponder` daemon on the remote host.)

In case there are absolutely *no* global addresses available that could be assigned to the `local` system, the final workaround is exactly the same as in IPv4: your `remote` system will need to do NAT. (That is, you would need to add a "MASQUERADE" rule in ip6tables, or its equivalent in nftables.)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately while the server has several /48 IPv6 prefixes, only singular addresses are routed to it. I am also doing this for the sake of excercise. I went with source nat. I will put the details in my answer

Comment: Then I assume you mean it's connected to several "shared" /48 prefixes, rather than actually "having" them all for itself? But even if the server only has a few individual addresses, you still should be able to take one more address and route it towards the client (with help from ndpresponder if necessary).

Comment: I'm not sure how it is done, probably the way you describe. I tried "moving" one address from remote's eth0 to local's tun0 but that did not work. Likely I need ndpresponder for that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @user1686 suggestion I decided to use source NAT on the IPv6 interface. It turns out that `remote` only has several *singular* IPv6 addresses assigned to it. This is unfortunately common.

On the `remote` machine I have added a source IPv6 nat with

```
nft add table ip6 nat
nft 'add chain ip6 nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100;  }'
nft add rule ip6 nat postrouting ip6 saddr fd00::ffff:0/48 oif \"eth0\" snat to [remote's IPv6 address]
```

The last line adds a source nat to packets from fd00::/48 that sends them on `eth0` with changed source address

Now executing `ping6 -I tun0 2001:4860:4860::8888` works fine as the packets are routed via the tunnel and SNAT'ed on the `remote`.

Note that this is a hack, and *not how IPv6 is supposed to operate*. This is done only because the `remote` server provider did not allocate an IPv6 block, but only single addresses.